# How can I manipulate a circular part of an image?

Tags: image-processing

I want to a specific part of an image, while leaving the rest of the image unchanged: The part should be circular en the center and radius of the circle should be easily adjustable.

So far I can only find ImageTake, which only lets me take rectangular parts of an image. Does a function exist for circular parts as well?